# Getting historical data for careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api

I'm wondering if there is a possible way to get historical data regarding job postings made through careers, even for postings that have already been filled. Does careers keep this data at all, and if so, would it be available through their API?

Comment: This was off topic, strictly-speaking.  Converted to a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) has nothing to do with Stack Overflow Careers.

Anyway, [**there is no API for accessing Stack Overflow Careers job listings**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158005/stackoverflow-careers-api).

[Best you can do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81529/is-there-any-public-api-that-allow-me-to-get-a-list-of-jobs-from-careers-2-0) is grab the most recent 1000 listings from [the Careers "all new jobs" RSS feed](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?).

Comment: Oh my apologies. Thought of all spots on the stackexchange, this was the most relevant for such a question. And shoot was afraid of that. Thanks for the heads up